# utf8 seems to break regex rule in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to debug why my UTF-8 isn't working right in my script. Here is the original code:

```
$lc_custom{"À propos de l'italie, en français"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"Здоровье"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"дерьмо"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"sécurité"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"security"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"health"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"french"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"ábc"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"crap"} = "foo bar";

my $text_repl = '| (' . join('|', map { my $v = quotemeta; $v = '\b'.$v if $v =~ /^\w/; $v .= '\b' if $v =~ /\w$/ } sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } keys %lc_custom) . ')';
```

Debugging that I get:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'foo' => '| (\\�\\�\\ propos\\ de\\ l\\\'italie\\,\\ en\\ fran\\�\\�ais\\b||||\\bsecurity\\b|\\bhealth\\b|\\bfrench\\b|\\�\\�bc\\b|\\bcrap\\b)'
        };
```

Here is my revised version with some more debugging:

```
my $text_repl = '| (' . join('|', map {
    print "FOO BAR: $_ \n";
    my $v = $_;
    $v = '\b' . $v if $v =~ /^\w/;
    $v .= '\b' if $v =~ /\w$/
} sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } keys %lc_custom) . ')';
```

I get:

```
FOO BAR: À propos de l'italie, en français 
FOO BAR: Здоровье 
FOO BAR: дерьмо 
FOO BAR: sécurité 
FOO BAR: security 
FOO BAR: health 
FOO BAR: french 
FOO BAR: ábc 
FOO BAR: crap 

$VAR1 = {
          'foo' => '| (\\QÀ propos de l\'italie, en français\\E\\b||||\\b\\Qsecurity\\E\\b|\\b\\Qhealth\\E\\b|\\b\\Qfrench\\E\\b|ábc\\E\\b|\\b\\Qcrap\\E\\b\\E)'
        };
```

It seems like all the keys don't like working when it has Russian in. Is there any reason that would be?

**UPDATE:** As requested, here is how it looks using:

```
use utf8;
my $test = '| (' . join('|', map { my $v = quotemeta; $v = '\b'.$v if $v =~ /^\w/; $v .= '\b' if $v =~ /\w$/ } sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } keys %lc_custom) . ')';
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper({ BLA => $test });
```

Gives:

```
"BLA" => "| (\\\303\\\200\\ propos\\ de\\ l\\'italie\\,\\ en\\ fran\\\303\\\247ais\\b||||\\bsecurity\\b|\\bhealth\\b|\\bfrench\\b|\\\303\\\241bc\\b|\\bcrap\\b)"
```

Comment: Does your script have a `use utf8;` in it at the start?

Comment: @Shawn it does indeed

Comment: Do you enable UTF-8 for streams, since the problem is when it's printed?  Like `use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));` at the beginning

Comment: Can you add `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` and update the dumps to show what you get with that?

Comment: @zdim the problem isn't about how its printed - its the missing values (notice `||||` , where it should have all the Russian versions in).

Comment: It looks like you are using `\w` to match against text encoded using UTF-8, but that makes no sense. `\w` should be used against decoded text (string of Unicode Code Points)

Comment: @ikegami as requested, please see the OP (updated)

Comment: Thanks, but I already deduced the info that provides. My later comment stands.

Comment: btw, that `use utf8;` is useless there. It would have to be before `$lc_custom{"Здоровье"} = "foo bar";`.

Comment: @ikegami good point about the `use utf8` position - it was further up, but I put it in there to show it was there :) For your other point - are you saying I need to do `utf8::upgrade($string)` to make the \w match? (https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.0/utf8.html seems to suggest that). Would that be a correct assumption?

Comment: I didn't mention anything in the comments that would be helped by `utf8::upgrade($string)`. There is a problem I didn't mention that could be helped by `utf8::upgrade($string)`, but you're better off using `use feature qw( unicode_strings );` or `use 5.014;`

Comment: @ikegami I didn't realize how necessary `unicode_strings` is (it seems as soon as any Unicode is around) --- so it should really be "on" for _all_ Unicode-aware code? (Or `use 5.014` +)

Comment: @zdim It fixes instances of The Unicode Bug in Perl itself. As such, it only matters for strings that contain at least one character in 80..FF and no character above FF. But still, it's a good thing :)

Comment: @ikegami Right, the [Unicode bug section in perlunicode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#The-%22Unicode-Bug%22) is most informative! ... I didn't know.  So any snippet dealing with Unicode should have it, plain and simple. (I don't know that I've _ever_ seen it here)

Comment: @zdim, Most of the time, decoded text will be in an "upgraded" scalar. So triggering T.U.B. unintentionally is pretty rare. But for some reason, `use utf8; ++$h{"é"}; Dump((keys(%h))[0])` produces a downgraded scalar. Don't ask my why. (Both `$s` and the keys are "upgraded" in `use utf8; my $s = "é"; Dump($s); ++$h{$s}; Dump((keys(%h))[0])`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decode your inputs; encode your outputs. The problems stems from the lack of doing the former. The keys of `%lc_custom` are strings of text encoded using UTF-8. You generally don't want to work with encoded text; you want to work with decoded text.

Both `quotemeta` and the `\w` regex character class expect to be provided decoded text. It doesn't make sense to pass encoded text to them. But that's what you're doing.

---

Let's look at a simple example.

```perl
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;

# "д♠" encoded using UTF-8 (encoded text).
my $utf8 = "\320\264\342\231\240";
say length($utf8);
print Dumper($utf8);
print Dumper(quotemeta($utf8));
say length(quotemeta($utf8));

say "";

# "д♠" as decoded text (Unicode Code Points).
my $ucp = "\x{434}\x{2660}";
say length($ucp);
print Dumper($ucp);
print Dumper(quotemeta($ucp));
say length(quotemeta($ucp));
```

```
5
$VAR1 = "\320\264\342\231\240";
$VAR1 = "\320\264\342\\\231\\\240";
7

2
$VAR1 = "\x{434}\x{2660}";
$VAR1 = "\x{434}\\\x{2660}";
3
```

Note that `quotemeta($utf8)` inserted 2 backslashes in the middle of the encoding of "♠" and none before it. On the other hand, `quotemeta($ucp)` added a single backslash between the two characters.

In short, you are passing garbage to `quotemeta`, and you are getting garbage back.

---

Perl expects its source code to be encoded using ASCII, unless you tell it it's encoded using UTF-8 by using `use utf8;`.

```perl
use 5.014;      # Or: use strict; use feature qw( say unicode_strings );
use warnings;

# Tell Perl the source code is encoded using UTF-8.
use utf8;

# Tell Perl the terminal provides/expects UTF-8.
# Also sets the default for `open`.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;

# From the question, verbatim.
my %lc_custom;
$lc_custom{"À propos de l'italie, en français"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"Здоровье"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"дерьмо"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"sécurité"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"security"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"health"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"french"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"ábc"} = "foo bar";
$lc_custom{"crap"} = "foo bar";

# From the question, verbatim.
my $text_repl = '| (' . join('|', map { my $v = quotemeta; $v = '\b'.$v if $v =~ /^\w/; $v .= '\b' if $v =~ /\w$/ } sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } keys %lc_custom) . ')';

say $text_repl;
print Dumper($text_repl);
```

Output:

```
| (\bÀ\ propos\ de\ l\'italie\,\ en\ français\b|\bЗдоровье\b|\bsécurité\b|\bsecurity\b|\bhealth\b|\bдерьмо\b|\bfrench\b|\bcrap\b|\bábc\b)
$VAR1 = "| (\\b\x{c0}\\ propos\\ de\\ l\\'italie\\,\\ en\\ fran\x{e7}ais\\b|\\b\x{417}\x{434}\x{43e}\x{440}\x{43e}\x{432}\x{44c}\x{435}\\b|\\bs\x{e9}curit\x{e9}\\b|\\bsecurity\\b|\\bhealth\\b|\\b\x{434}\x{435}\x{440}\x{44c}\x{43c}\x{43e}\\b|\\bfrench\\b|\\bcrap\\b|\\b\x{e1}bc\\b)";
```

Note that the `unicode_strings` feature fixes a bug that could prevent `À` from matching `\w`. `use 5.014;` enables that feature (and more).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. That makes sense., All working well now :)

Comment: "Perl expects its source code to be encoded using ASCII" -- the default without `use utf8` is latin1.

Comment: @Ether, No, its not. Try `use utf8; sub fête { }` in a file encoded using UTF-8 and `sub fête { }` in a file encoded using iso-8859-1, for example. String and regex literals are, however, 8-bit-clean, so you can create strings encoded using any ASCII-based encoding (including, but not limited to, iso-8859-1)

Answer (score -2):

Typically, pretty much as soon as I posted this I came up with the solution! So it seems like Perl keys don't like having Russian in? I've never needed to do that before, so maybe thats why its not come up. I tweaked the code so that I used an array with a hashref in to create the regex instead:

```
my $text_repl = '| (';
foreach my $x (@lc_words) {
    my $v = quotemeta $x->{word};
    $v = '\b' . $v if $v =~ /^\w/;
    $v .= '\b' if $v =~ /\w$/;
    $text_repl .= "|$v";
}
$text_repl .= ')';
```

This now works perfectly =)

Comment: um ... so how do Russians write programs in Perl?  Or how about Gernams -- or Chinese? Glad you found a workaround but that can't be the problem...

Comment: Re "*So it seems like Perl keys don't like having Russian in?*", Not true